# Is there a standard for roundtrip message time in the majordomo pattern using ZeroMQ and how is that measured or found?

Tags: zeromq

I am not sure if my ZeroMQ Majordomo implementation is correct. I believe the guide suggests that this pattern can handle tens of thousands of messages per second using a synchronous-roundtrip pattern. My present solution seems to struggles to send more than one thousand messages per second. My goal is to get as close to I can to running at least ten thousand messages per second.

I am running all of the components of the Majrodomo pattern on separate Windows 2012 servers, each with 12 processors and 32 GB of ram, so I am sure there cannot be resource constraints. All of these servers are running within the same network as well, meaning they are not traversing a firewall. My code is runs slower due to the business logic incorporated into it, so for my speed testing I went back to the simple test code the is provided in the ZeroMQ guide. These are supposedly the clients that are used in the guide to show the messages per second. I have tried in a few different languages as well, including Delphi and C#, neither of which seem to be able to reach the promised speeds.

Code can be found for those here:
http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all

I am wondering if I am expecting too much from the pattern. Roundtrip message times in the pattern seem to sit around 25ms when sending from 100 clients to a single broker, and then to 100 workers and back through the pattern. This seems slow, and sending 10000 messages from these clients takes about 4 seconds, which isn't anywhere near the promise of tens of thousands per second. Am I expecting too much of this pattern, or is there something I'm missing here.

By the way, I've seen posts about HWM (high water mark) being hit, but given that were in a synchronous pattern I don't believe that could be an issue, since we only are able to queue a max number of messages equivalent to our client count.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *...struggles to send more than one thousand messages per second ... goal is to get as close to I can to running at least ten thousand messages per second.*

ZeroMQ eco-system evolves beyond the state, when the performance testing was published.

### The best first step :

is to explicitly publish all details of the System-under-Test - a.k.a. **`SuT`** ( for each of the hosts, its hardware details ( best by `hwloc`-alike "fingerprint" ), O/S configuration details ( prio, backgound workloads, costs of virtualised machine ( if applicable - i.e. how much vCPU-clocks were actually stolen from "inside" of the VM by the external hypervisor ),  interfaces - O/S buffer settings, I/F-free-capacity ( workload background ), ToS / VLAN or other LAN-interconnect performance modifying details, LAN-interconnect L2-switching silicon theoretical performance ceilings and background workloads present prior, during and after the `SuT` episodes.

### Next comes the code :

a full copy of all the code - a.k.a. the **MCVE**-(inspect-able and repeat-able)-code. Given no code present here so far, no one can judge your actual observations as per the root-cause of the observed **`~ 1k [msgs/s]`**

### Next comes a definition of "reference point" to be used in test :

at which defined / given "reference"-point(s) the `SuT` ought get measured and what are the expected ranges for the expected TaT in `[ms]`.

I work rather long with ZeroMQ DLL-s ( since 2.11 - so it's indeed quite a long time ) and I believe one can easily either overload an AccessNode with an ingress traffic or, as easily as the former case, suffocate the ZeroMQ infrastructure, if improper configuration was let in and a service performance will decrease, if not degrade, if no due measures were taken to configure all the resources that stay on the service's critical path.

Without hard facts ( as declared in the previous few steps ) there remains but guesses or unsupported ( yet ) opinions.